# Artin symbol property

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

In Serge Lang's Algebraic Number Theory, Chapter 10, it defines **Artin symbol** as follows:

> Let $k$ a number field, $K/k$  be an abelian Galois extension, and $p$ be a prime of $k$ which is unramified in $K$, let $B$ be a prime in $K$ lying above $p$, then there exists a unique element $\sigma$ of the Galois group $G$, lying in the decomposition group $G_B$ having the effect $\sigma a \equiv a^{N_p} 
>  \left(\mod B \right), a\in o_K.$ ($N_p = |o_k/p|$ )
>
> This element $\sigma$ depends only on $p$, and is denoted by $(p,K/k)$ , and will be called Artin symbol of $p$ in $G$.

Then it states a property:

> Let $K/k$ be abelian and $E/k$ be finite, both Galois. Let $p$ be a prime in $k$ unramified in $K$ and let $q$ be a prime of $E$ lying above $p$. Then $\mbox{res}_K (q, KE/E) = (p, K/k)^f$ where $f$ is the residue class degree $[o_E/q:o_k/p].$

But in order for $(q,KE/E)$ to make sense, $q$ must be unratified in $KE$, why is it the case here?

Comment: It’s too late for me to force myself to think clearly on this problem, but let me point out the corresponding situation in the purely local, complete situation: start with the $p$-adic field k (finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$), and a finite unramified extension thereof, $K$. Now take any finite extension $E$ of $k$. Then it should be clear that $KE$ is unramified over $E$, ’cause $K\supset k$ is generated by roots of unity of order prime to $p$, and these same quantities generate $KE$ over $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathfrak P$ be a prime ideal in $\mathcal O_{KE}$ lying above $p$. Also let $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak P \cap (K \cap E)$, $\mathfrak q = \mathfrak P \cap E$. Additionally it's well-known that $KE$ is Galois over $k$, so it makes sense to talk about inertia fields and so on.

Now let $L_I$ be the inertia field of $\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p$ and $L_E$ the inertia field of $\mathfrak q/\mathfrak p$. As $L_I$ contains every intermediate field in which ramification doesn't occur we get that $L_E \subseteq L_I$. In the same manner we have that $L_I \cap E \subseteq L_E$, as no ramification occurs in $K \cap E \subseteq E \cap L_E$. Thus $L_E = E \cap L_I$. Moreover as $\text{Gal}\left(\frac{KE}{K} \right)\cong \text{Gal}\left(\frac{E}{K \cap E}\right)$ we get that $L_I \leftrightarrow L_E$ under the natural isomorphism.

Finally we get that $e(\mathfrak P|\mathfrak p) = [KE:L_I] = [E:L_E] = e(\mathfrak q|\mathfrak p)$. However by multiplicativity $e(\mathfrak P|\mathfrak p) = e(\mathfrak P|\mathfrak q)e(\mathfrak q|\mathfrak p)$ and thus $e(\mathfrak P|\mathfrak q)=1$. In other words we get that $\mathfrak q$ doesn't ramify in $\mathcal O_{KE}$.

Hence the proof.

**REMARK:** Note as $k \subseteq E$ is finite extension all the ramification indices and extension degrees we worked with are finite integers, so it makes sense to perform all those operations.

Comment: Does “$L_I$ contains every non-ramified intermediate field ” need the condition that $K \cap E$ be complete with regard to absolute value induced from $\mathfrak p$? I'm not sure but all reference I searched seem to have some complete condition.

Comment: @CYC To be fair I'm not too familiar with infinite extensions, so I would refrain from talking about it and saying something wrong. Nevertheless if $K/k$ is a finite extension I believe that above argument should hold. Also for finite extension the inertia group of $\mathfrak P/\mathfrak q$ is the intersection of the inertia group of $\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p$ and the subgroup corresponding to the field $E$. Thus in our notation we would have $L_I = L_EK$. Again I feel that this is true for finite extension, but I'm not sure about infinite ones.

Comment: @CYC Anyway could you point me to a reference that requires the complete condition?

Comment: After rechecking Lang's book, it seems to assume $K/k$ is finite already, as that's what it assumes when defining decomposition group $G_B$.

BTW, is it standard fact that inertia field contains every intermediate field in which ramification doesn't occur?

Comment: @CYC I feel that most of the books covering the Decomposition and Inertia Group topics also mention that fact. Anyway you can find a proof in Marcus' "Algebraic Number Theory". (Also I recommend reading this book, if you haven't done it yet). Also a quick Google search yields this site: https://algebrateahousejmath.wordpress.com/2016/11/28/decomposition-and-inertia-fields/, which gives a similar proof.